# How important are Perf rating and Raider IO Score for getting into pugging HC/Mythic/M+ content

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am wondering if this has an impact for the majority of players trying to pug HC/Mythic/M+ content.

Currently I am clearing Mythic and doing high (+18-+21) Mythic+ content with my guild so I personally (currently) dont have the need to pug, but I am wondering if should I leave, if the Warcraft logs Perf ratings and my Mythic+ score will significantly boost my chances of being taken in the dungeon/raidfinger.

What are the experienes there? Are many people stalking chars for those things? Will it increase my chances significantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience in this and past expansions most leaders are too lazy to check for scores. If you have the proper achievements you get invited in most cases. This might be different in mythic raid pugs.. I haven't tried those yet.

If you have the Curve achievement (Ahead of the Curve: [*latest final boss here*]; kill the final boss on heroic difficulty) you can pretty much join every pug raid in NM and HM. Logs are mostly irrelevant and only a very few raid leaders check for those. When I posted the Cutting Edge achievement (kill the final boss on mythic difficulty) it was usually an instant invite when the gear was ok... There wasn't enough delay to assume they checked my logs.

In M+ it's mostly about the character and class. Some classes get no invite at all, regardless of their performance logs and gear. With the right class they still want high gear and the achievement Keystone Master (complete a +15 in time) and after that it's pretty easy.

---

In short: Good achievements and gear are worth more than performance logs.

Comment: this just applies to the casual side of things, theres addons for raider.io score checking etc, and im 100% confident that better raider.io score gets u faster invited into higher m+ groups.

The same way ilvl determines if you get picked for raids aswell

Comment: raider.io only applies to the few people using it as well ;-) There are a bunch of addons and way to determine what you're doing: wowprogress, raider.io, wowheroes,... etc pp. basically they all do the same. If you want to be really sure you'll want to use warcraftlogs and check for yourself.